# Presigned Link expires in Expires=172000 but expires in less than 24 hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a presigned link with S3 and it should expire in 172000
minutes, but it did expire within 24 hours. What is the problem?

The parameter i used was:
--expires-in 172000

The link itself worked perfectly during the first hour.

Comment: That number is in seconds.  172000 seconds is just about 2 days.  How long do you perceive that it was valid?

Comment: Are you using temporary credentials to create the pre-signed url?

Comment: 2 days i was expecting

Comment: @jellycsc no, they are not temporary

Comment: Were the credentials generated on an EC2 instance or your own computer? If an incorrect timezone is set on the computer, the expiration timestamp might be incorrect.